# Calling bin/magento return an exception

Tags: exception, magento2.3, bin-magento, request

I have a Magento 2.3.0 website that works correctly but suddenly (maybe after a products import, but also other various activities were done) when I try to call ANY (reindex, deploy...) command of "bin/magento" it returns me:

`An exception was raised while creating "Request"; no instance returned`

I tried to add more debugging output with `-vvv` but the error remain the same.

Anyone know what could be the cause or any method to further debug it?

Comment: I think you need check logs, enable PHP log also. I had this issue and after enabling PHP errors I was able to see error on frontend. Problem was missing version number in setup module table of one module

Comment: I have Magento and PHP log and error reporting enabled but it looks like it returns only that exception that looks raised by the call `$bootstrapApplication->bootstrap($configuration);` of `/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php`

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be caused due to the **magento / .htaccess** file missing under the folder magentoroot/../bin

Also,check the current PHP version in your terminal using below command

```
php -v
```

To know the path of the php

```
whereis php
```

Based on the Magento version, you need to set the php version.

Answer (score 1):

Set **PHP Version 7.2** Your problem is solved. 
I have checked and it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete all the cached files with the following command 
`rm -rf cache/* page_cache/* di/* generation/*`

and re-run the reindex.
If it's a live website, maybe will be worth enabling the maintenance mode before running the command

Comment: Tried to clean them but error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Change the **PHP version** according to your **Magento version**. it should be working.